# DNS: redirect all www to non-www-https

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy

On my godaddy dns settings, how do I make all www requests to become non-www reqests as https to my server?

I can setup a forward for www. subdomain to https://example.com however, that only works for http: requests.

Comment: This is not a function of DNS.

Comment: thank you. I think that is also something people have to learn, so why the downvote?

Also, constructive hint on how to do it would help me or readers.

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted. Only the person who did it knows, and they are not required to explain it.

Comment: Isn't (subdomain) forwarding a DNS function? So why does it work for non-ssl but not for ssl? Does this make sense?

Comment: No, it is not a DNS function. It's done in HTTP.

Comment: `@ IN A 198.251.86.133` will do it

Comment: DNS is only for resolving a domain name to an IP-address, or doing the reverse lookup from an IP-address to a domain. What you are asking for has to happen on a web-server that handles the HTTP-request. When a client sends a HTTP request to the server, the DNS server/client has already finished their work.

Comment: Yeah, but forwarding seems to be a DNS function. So why does www. subdomain forwarding to non-www work with http but not with https at many providers?